# Should my custom DocumentsProvider use a ParcelFileDescriptor to stream the selected file?

Tags: android, streaming, uri, android-contentprovider

In my app, I am using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for processing/displaying images, and [ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) for displaying video. Both can take a direct URI link to a file and will handle streaming the contents, buffering it, resizing it, handling cache management, etc. In other words, all the hard stuff!

The format of this URI and what happens under the covers when using the Android File Chooser and custom Document Providers is key to the issue here.

Because I want a seamless user experience for selecting image, video and audio for use in the app whether the file desired is local to the mobile device or on the Internet, I decided to use the Android File Chooser. These means that I have to write or otherwise provide a `DocumentsProvider` instance in keeping with the Storage Access Framework for each online resource that does not already support SAF (i.e. DropBox, SnapChat, Instagram, etc.).

Although it took a bit to get the hang of it, writing DocumentsProvider classes isn't overly difficult.

The issue starts with the fact that the URI returned back from the Chooser (and thus what I'm storing as a persistent URI for later usage by my app) is of the `content://` variety - it is not the `http://` or `https://` type that Glide/ExoPlayer normally works with.

So for example, assume the `content://` type of string is used as an argument ultimately to the `.load()` method below:

```
            GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(media.getPathToMedia()))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform())
                    .placeholder(placeHolder)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_image_error)
                    .into(imageView);
```

What happens next is the `DocumentsProvider` instance associated with that URI ultimately gets an `openDocument()` call. So for example, I wrote a custom DropboxProvider. The URI returned from the Chooser that I store in my app's DB looks something like:

`content://authority_string/document/XXX-YYY-ZZZ`.

When passing that string to the `load()` method of Glide, my `openDocument()` method of the DropboxProvider class gets called, and in there I parse out the document ID, log in to DropBox, and use their API to snag the file locally and  return a `ParcelFileDescriptor` wrapping a `File` object that points to that downloaded file. The caller can then resolve this descriptor object appropriately and Glide loads it properly.

All this works fine.

However, it struck me that this approach isn't optimal for several reasons, the chief of which is that while Glide/ExoPlayer have no clue how to locate a file on DropBox, once they have a direct link to it they support the fetching and buffering and streaming and cache management etc. likely far better than I am doing it.

It seems to me it is much better to obey the "separation of concerns" approach and NOT have my app in the business of "owning" the download/stream and cache management responsibilities. Just have it own the "identification of the file" responsibility.

So this is really the crux of my question - where is the best "cut off" line here in terms of who is responsible for what?

I can't get away from the fact that the result of the chooser is a `content://` link. That's just how the Storage Access Framework is built.

But what I could do is augment my Provider to identify that direct link ahead of time, and return it in the Cursor when the user initially selects the file. Then upon completion of the file selection, use standard Resolver() methods to capture that info into my `Media` object, which I then persist into my DB:

```
public static void populateMediaFromUri(Context context, Media media, Uri uri) {
    *
    *
    *
    String path = null;

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if ( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {

            String directLink = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AbstractStorageProvider.COLUMN_DIRECT_LINK));
            if ( directLink == null ) {
                path = uri.toString();
            } else {
                path = directLink;
            }

            *
            *
            *
            media.setPathToMedia(path);

        }
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        Timber.d("Error resolving to path, requested was %s, error was %s", uri.getPath(), e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if ( cursor != null ) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

I can then use that direct link path later to pass to Glide or ExoPlayer instead of the `content://` based URI I am getting back now from the File Chooser. This would allow Glide/ExoPlayer to completely handle getting those files (my custom provider would no longer be called to resolve getting the file).

Or do I continue to use the `content://` type URI in my calls to Glide/ExoPlayer and investigate how to create a `ParcelFileDescriptor` that wraps a pipe to the actual file and return that from `openDocument()`? This seems to be hinted at as a possible approach in Ian's [fine article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a) in the section ***Getting to the meat of a document: the bytes!***.

But again, in this case doing so sure does seem to be duplicating efforts already present in those two tools (and I haven't yet been able to find examples of using ParcelFileDescriptor in this way).

Comment: "But what I could do is augment my Provider to identify that direct link ahead of time, and return it in the Cursor when the user initially selects the file" -- this feels like possibly a security problem and possibly a terms-of-service problem. Your `DocumentsProvider` is available to every app on the device, not just your own. Of course, the terms-of-service problem extends to your core implementation as well, as some of these providers may not want you effectively exposing their APIs to arbitrary other apps, even wrapped in a `DocumentsProvider`.

Comment: Interesting point. But I am only using public API's that can also be done directly on the website. In the case of DropBox for example, the ability to create a shared link on a file for the public is available directly from the web interface (and programmatically via the API).  But good idea to check out the terms of service for sure.